# What does this warning message mean, tensorflow:Efficient allreduce is not supported for 4 IndexedSlices?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I am using tensorflow V2.3 and the server has 2 GPUs. With MirroredStrategy, I get the following warning message:

> tensorflow:Efficient allreduce is not supported for 4 IndexedSlices

How does it impact my computing? What do I have to do to improve the situation? I use 'nvtop' to monitor the GPUs and both GPUs work close to 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, MirroredStrategy.reduce will do a concatenation of IndexedSlices on one device, and broadcast the result back to all GPUs. This is not efficient, hence the warning. This is a known limitation and the current suggestion is to use MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy, which has a slightly better implementation for handling IndexedSlices. Despite its name, MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy can be used with a single worker without additional setup. [See this github thread for more info.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41898)